# Template's cache issue with magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento, caching

I work on a template in **Mangento 1.9** but when I refresh my page, the **content is not update**. I've delete the cache in the cache manager and I've run a personnal script with this simple line `<?php opcache_reset(); ?>`.

But nothing changes. Do you know other cache on Magento which can store the template ?

Comment: It can be cache on web-server level. For example, Nginx can check is file modified or not and return it from cache. Also external cache systems, like Varnish can used. Finally, you have cache in broswer which not refreshed just by page refreshing or 'F5' clicking. Please provide more details about your server environment.

Comment: We use redice and opcache on a Nginx server. We clear both but nothing changes.I clear my local cache and we check the page from another network and the result was the same.

Comment: Can you restart nginx process?

Comment: Not now because the website is in prod but tomorrow morning (France) we'll try that.

Comment: We restart Nginx process but nothing changes

Comment: Ok, let's check did you edit correct template? Please post here path to your template and values from System > Configuration > Design: Package (Current package name) and Themes (Templates).

Comment: Infact I create a new page, I add the label to display my block, the issue appends again. I reflush all caches and it's work. I don't know why. Thx for your time and advice.